# ERROR: could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/share/extension/mysql_fdw.control": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I want to setup MySQL FDW (Foreign Data Wrapper) for PostgreSQL in **Windows**.

I installed pgAdmin III in **Windows**, which also installs postgreSQL. I then ran this command in the SQL window of pgAdmin. I got this error:

ERROR: could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/share/extension/mysql_fdw.control": No such file or directory

It looks to me that I need to do a few pre-requisite steps. But I don't find any proper documentation which walks me through step by step. You may redirect to this page:
https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw

But I think these instructions are for Linux. I don't know how to make them work for Windows. Also, the first few instructions are quite vague. If I am running postgres on a windows desktop, what all do I need to do? I don't know of any make command or export command in Windows.

Comment: There are a lot of extensions which are not available as pre-built Windows binaries. The MySQL FDW is one of them. You will have to compile it yourself - which requires installing a C compiler and the necessary libraries. This blog post might help: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/

Comment: Compiling `mysql_fdw` won't be trivial. You might be able to ask nicely and get EDB to compile it, but I wouldn't hold my breath. @a_horse_with_no_name has hit on only real solution: Compile it yourself in Visual Studio, making any required code changes to support Windows in the process.

Answer (score 1):

I was able today to successfully use the precompiled DLLs [found here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/postgresql-mingw-w64/files/) to integrate the `mysql_fdw 1.0.0` into a fresh PostgreSQL 9.3 32bit install from the official installers on Windows Server 2012 64bit.

Here is what I did:

- Install PostgreSQL 9.3.9 32bit from the [latest official installer](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows) (`postgresql-9.3.9-1-windows.exe`)
- Download `postgresql-9.3.1-standalone-32-(sqlite_fdw,www_fdw,mysql_fdw,ldap_fdw).7z` from http://sourceforge.net/projects/postgresql-mingw-w64/files/
- Extract the archive somewhere (let's assume `C:\somewhere\postgresql-9.3.1-standalone-32`).
- In the extracted folder, go to `C:\somewhere\postgresql-9.3.1-standalone-32\01_DLLs_32-DEPLOY_EXTS`
- run `deploy-x86-on-win64.bat` if running Windows 64 bit, `deploy-x86-on-win32.bat` otherwise.
- In PgAdmin III, right-click on your database (let's assume `postgres`), choose `New Object` > `New Extension`
- In the `New Extension...` dialog, open the drop-down list for the `Name` and select for `mysql_fdw`. (If not found, something must have messed up earlier.). Finish by clicking on `OK`.

If everything went well, that's it!

From this point on you will need to create the Foreign Server, the Foreign Table and so on.

I personally used the example given here at the bottom of the page: http://pgxn.org/dist/mysql_fdw/1.0.0/

Note: if using a 64bit build of PostgreSQL, I assume that the procedure should be similar, with the exception that you need to download `postgresql-9.3.1-standalone-64-(sqlite_fdw,www_fdw,mysql_fdw,ldap_fdw).7z`. But I haven't tested it! Mileage may vary.